# Grunt index task src globbing order

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 with a grunt task to get all the java-script files in my project and write them to my template index.html before build. The problem i have is the order the files are dependent on each other. For instance I need to create a script src='' to angular.js before ui-bootstrap-tpls.js otherwise I will get Reference errors. The index task src wildcard is getting the files in 'an order' and it's not the one that works for the dependency graph. Is there a way to customize this order without writing out each sub-directory individually and defeating the purpose of this hands-off template grunt task when adding new dependencies in future (i.e. I shouldn't have to add new directories)?

I have an index task registered (with wildcard source):

```
index: {
        dev: {
            dir: '<%= wwwroot_dir %>',
            src: [
               '<%= build_dir %>/wwwroot/**/*.js',
            ]
```

I then have a multi task:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('index', 'Process index.html template', function () {
    var dirRE = new RegExp('^(' + grunt.config('build_dir') + '/' + grunt.config('wwwroot_dir')
                                + '|' + grunt.config('compile_dir') + '/' + grunt.config('wwwroot_dir')
                                + '|' + grunt.config('build_dir')
                                + '|' + grunt.config('compile_dir')
                                + ')\/', 'g');

    var jsFiles = filterForJS(this.filesSrc).map(function (file) {
        return file.replace(dirRE, '');
    });

    var cssFiles = filterForCSS(this.filesSrc).map(function (file) {
        return file.replace(dirRE, '');
    });

    var sourcePath = userConfig.app_files.htmltemplate;

    grunt.file.copy(sourcePath, this.data.dir + '/index.html', {
        process: function (contents, path) {
            return grunt.template.process(contents, {
                data: {
                    scripts: jsFiles,
                    styles: cssFiles,
                    version: grunt.config('pkg.version')
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Example index.html

```
    <html data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="">
    <head>
      <title data-ng-bind="pageTitle">MY APP</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

      <!-- compiled CSS --><% styles.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= file %>" />
      <% }); %>

      <!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script>
      <% }); %>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-ui-view></div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Example directories defined (which I want to avoid if possible):

```
index: {
        dev: {
            dir: '<%= wwwroot_dir %>',
            src: [
                  '<%= wwwroot_dir %>/lib/angular/*.js',
                  '<%= wwwroot_dir %>/lib/angular-bootstrap/*.js',
                  ....etc
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little searching I found the following on [gruntjs.com](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks)

> Also, in order to simplify otherwise complicated globbing patterns, Grunt allows arrays of file paths or globbing patterns to be
>   specified. Patterns are processed in-order, with !-prefixed matches
>   excluding matched files from the result set. The result set is
>   uniqued.

As the files are uniqued, I have included the more important dependencies at the top and then used the wildcard afterwards. The uniqueness seems to have removed the second instance and not the first which works.

```
index: {
        dev: {
            dir: '<%= wwwroot_dir %>',
            src: [
                '<%= wwwroot_dir %>/lib/jquery/dist/*.js',
                '<%= wwwroot_dir %>/lib/angular/*.js',
               '<%= wwwroot_dir %>/lib/**/*.js',
            ]
        }
```